# Is it possible to have a Browser wrapper for a webapp?

Tags: javascript

Background; I have a web app that talks to the `webview` in a hybrid android mobile application. I want to do the same thing with a Web Browser. How can I inject a javascript similar to the javascript bridge in android?

I tried opening the web application using 
`window.open(url);`

I need to add javascript methods to the child window so the web application can call it.

I need to add it in such a way that the web application can call the javascript method on the child window like

`button.addEventListener ("click", function(){ window.obj.method(value);});`

Both windows are in the same domain.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is a bit unclear: (a) What does [Hybrid Mobile App](https://www.apteligent.com/2015/12/build-a-hybrid-mobile-application-with-android/) mean (which frameworks used) ? (b) Can you share more code as [example] !